# Shiny - Efficient way to use ggplot2(boxplot) & a 'reactive' subset function

Tags: r, ggplot2, google-visualization, plyr, shiny

I have a dataset with > 1000K rows and 5 columns. (material & prices been the relevant columns)

I have written a 'reactive' Shiny app which uses ggplot2 to create a boxplot of the price of the various materials. 
e.g the user selects 4-5 materials from a list and then Shiny creates a boxplot of the price of each material :

*Price spread of:* Made of Cotton, Made of Paper, Made of Wood

It also creates a **material combination** data plot of the pricing spread of the combination of all the materials

e.g Boxplot of
*Price spread of:* Made of Cotton & Paper & Wood

It is working relatively quickly for the sample dataset (~5000 rows) but I am worried about scaling it effectively.

The dataset is static so I look at the following solutions:

1. Calculate the quartile ranges of the various materials (data <-
   summary(data)) and then use googleViz to create a candle stick,

   *however I run into problems when trying to calculate the **material combination** plot as there are over 100 materials, so calculating
   all the possible combinations offline is not feasible.*
2. Calculate the quartile ranges of the various materials (data <- summary(data)) and then create a matrix which stores the row numberof the summary data (min,median,max,1st&3rd quartile) for each material. I can then use some rough calculations to establish the    summary() data for the **material combination** plot, 
   and then plot using GoogleVIZ however I have little experience with this type of calculation using Shiny.

Can anyone suggest the most robust and scalable way to calculate & boxplot reactive subsets using Shiny?

I understand this a question related to method, rather than code, but I am new to the capabilities of R and am still digesting the different class capabilities, and don't want to 'miss a trick' so to speak.

As always thanks!

Please see below for methods reviewed.

Quartile Clustering: A quartile based technique for Generating Meaningful Clusters 
http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1203/1203.4157.pdf

[Conditionally subsetting and calculating a new variable in dataframe in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056766/conditionally-subsetting-and-calculating-a-new-variable-in-dataframe-in-shiny)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really have a dataset that has more than 1000K, which is 1M. It is probably in a flat file or in a database. You can always do some precalculations and store the result in a database table and use shiny app to call that table instead of loading everything into R every time people open up your shiny app.

I have built several shiny apps for internal use and the lesson I have learned is that: before you build your app, you need to carefully think about, how can I minimize the calculations for R and at the same time deliver the info to app user. Some of our data is 10billion+ and use Hive query will take more than 1 hour. Then I ended up precalculate result and put it on the crontab to update the result table every midnight.

I prefer, maybe your method2? or store the precalculation in a mysql database. (Maybe a Python script update the table once a day if you need some real-time feature later).