# R Shiny: Using variables from output for further calculation outside of function

Tags: r, variables, server, shiny, global

My shiny app looks as follows so far (extract):

```
ui <- fluidPage(


 headerPanel("title"),

   sidebarLayout(

         sidebarPanel(


              h4("header"),
              tags$hr(),


  # Input: Bilanzpositionen Passiv ----

      fileInput("file1", "Kollektive hochladen",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv")),
)
)
)
# # # # # 

server <- function(input, output) {



  output$contents <- renderTable({


    req(input$file1)

    bipop <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,

                  sep = input$sep,
                  quote = input$quote)

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(bipop))
    }
    else {
      bipop
    }


  })

}
```

Later on in code (server) I want to extract some data from the Input "bipop" to create some new tables which shall be part of another output.

My trial

```
monate <- bipop[,4]
```

doesn't work: "Error: ... undefined columns selected..." and "Error: object ... not found"

How can I define the variable "bipop" as global, so that I can use it outside of the code from "output"?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi please add your UI side as well. In addition which data are you using? Otherwise this question can't be answered, because your code example is incomplete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I build a reactive dataframe in R / Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443625/how-do-i-build-a-reactive-dataframe-in-r-shiny)

Comment: @5th: I've editted my question,@pieca: I think it doesn't help here. I Need to manipulate "bipop" after the csv had been uploaded.

Comment: Read `bipop` reactively i.e. put `read.csv` inside `reactive`. Then you can use `bipop` wherever you want using `bipop()`

Answer (score 1):

To expand @A.Suliman's comment, here is a complete example.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("header"),
      tags$hr(),

      # Input: Bilanzpositionen Passiv ----
      fileInput("file1", "Kollektive hochladen",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv"))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),
      verbatimTextOutput("test")
    )

  )
)

# # # # # 

server <- function(input, output) {

  bipop <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    bipop()
  })

  output$test <- renderPrint({
    summary(bipop())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```