# R Shiny: Create and output new table from table input

Tags: r, input, shiny, output

This is a continuation of the [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513364/r-shiny-using-variables-from-output-for-further-calculation-outside-of-function/51535823#51535823).

What I try to do is to create a new table from an Input and print that new table as an Output.

I want to extract columns from the input to create several other tables, too.

My code gives an Error: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

 headerPanel("title"),

  sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(

  h4("header"),
  tags$hr(),

      fileInput("file3", "description",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                           ".csv",".txt")),

  tags$hr(),

  width = 6
),

mainPanel(

  tableOutput("contents3"),

  width = 6

)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {


# input table:

  implop <- eventReactive(input$file3,{
    read.csv(input$file3$datapath,
                sep = input$sep)
  })  

# create new table:

    ip.lzb <- reactive ({ data.frame(cf=rep(0,21))

    ip.lzb()[11,] <- sum(implop()[ 1,2])
    ip.lzb()[12,] <- sum(implop()[ 2,2])
    ip.lzb()[13,] <- sum(implop()[ 3,2])
    ip.lzb()[14,] <- sum(implop()[ 4,2])
    ip.lzb()[15,] <- sum(implop()[ 5,2])
    ip.lzb()[16,] <- sum(implop()[ 6,2])
    ip.lzb()[17,] <- sum(implop()[7:9,2])
    ip.lzb()[18,] <- sum(implop()[10:12,2])
    ip.lzb()[19,] <- sum(implop()[13:24,2])
    ip.lzb()[20,] <- sum(implop()[25:60,2])
    ip.lzb()[21,] <- sum(implop()[61:120,2])

    rownames(ip.lzb()) <- rnames # predefined

    ip.lzb()[21,] <- ip.lzb()[21,] - sum(ip.lzb()[1:21,])

})       


# return new table:

  output$contents3 <- renderTable({

    ip.lzb()

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It's not valid to create `ip.lzb` by `reactive` and then call it inside the reactive like so `ip.lzb()[11,]`

Comment: Can you include a small fraction of your csv-file?

Comment: It consists of two columns (a = 1:120, b = different numerics)