# Returning a dataframe in a reactive function in R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

Working with a Shiny Dashboard, ui.r, server.r and several r scripts that contain functions.

Base problem is:  I have two data sets that I bring into the server.r and I pass those to a function the prepares/cleanses the data sets and then binds them together and should return a complete dataframe.  The dataFrame should be reactive.  Here is what I have so far:

In the server.r I load the data prior to the function(input, output, session).  Then I have:

```
################server.r  code #########################
data <- reactive({
   testDF <- prepData(data1, data2)
})
```

The prepData function does a variety of things but ends with:

```
####################prepData function return#################
 return(rbind(data1, data2))
```

If I use something like:

```
############## server.r code#######################
value = nrow(data()),
```

Then the code returns the correct value.  However I would prefer to just return the data frame as I did with testDF.

Shiny will throw and error in the UI of object 'testDF' not found.

I tried working through:  [How do I build a reactive dataframe in R / Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443625/how-do-i-build-a-reactive-dataframe-in-r-shiny)
using the code:

```
dataR <- prepData(data1, data2)

makeReactiveBinding(dataR)
```

This still throws the error.  The function is clearly working and has been validated but there must be something I don't understand about the reactive component of utilizing this function.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

**server.ui**

```
function(input, output, session) { 

### PreProcess the Data

data <- reactive({
  testDF <- prepData(bdata, qdata)
})

#dataR <- prepData(bData, qData)

#makeReactiveBinding(dataR)

### Information Box Populations

output$monthlytransactions = renderInfoBox({
infoBox(
  title = "Payments",
  value = nrow(data()),
  icon = icon("comments-dollar"),
  color = "blue"
)
})

output$monthlyGrossDollars = renderInfoBox({
infoBox(
  title = "Payments",
  value = sum(testDF$GrossAmount),
  icon = icon("comments-dollar"),
  color = "blue"
)
})

 }
```

**prepData**

```
############# FUNCTIONS ##############
prepData <- function(beamData, qlawData){ 

##Processing##
#Join DFs
return(rbind(bData, qData))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of reactive expressions as being functions that return a value. So you're getting the `object 'testDF' not found` error because `testDF` only exists within the scope of the `data` reactive object (function).

When you create a reactive expression:

```
data <- reactive({
  testDF <- prepData(bdata, qdata)
})
```

what you're actually doing is creating a function that returns a value. In this case, you run `prepData()`, save the result in the object `testDF` and then implicitly return that value (since R implicitly returns the value of the last line of a function). You access that value by calling `data()`, since that's the name of the reactive expression that returns your value, not `testDF`, since that object is deleted once the function has finished running.

If you want `testDF` to contain the result of `prepData`, just change the name of the reactive expression like so:

```
testDF <- reactive({
    prepData(bdata, qdata)
})

testDF() # this will return the value you want
```

---

Calling the reactive expression *does actually* return a data frame which you can subset and work with as normal. So you can work with it just like a data frame (but don't forget the parentheses!):

```
data()$GrossAmount
data()[data()$GrossAmount > 100, c('name', 'date')]
```

Comment: In this situation testdf() is still more of a function.  What I am looking for is the actual dataFrame so testDF where I am able to reference the columns in the dataFrame and put it through additional calculation criteria.  For example:


      `output$monthlyGrossDollars = renderInfoBox({
      infoBox(
      title = "Payments",
      value = sum(testDF$GrossAmount),
      icon = icon("comments-dollar"),
      color = "blue"
      )`

In this situation I am able to directly access the column GrossAmount and perform a sum across it.

Comment: that is what I was missing I think is the inherent return of a data frame.  I am validating the results but this looks to be spot on, much appreciated!